# MySql Date Time Comparison

Tags: mysql

I have a table `abc` with a field `datetime_abc` type-> DATETIME in mysql.
and table `xyz` with a field `datetime_xyz` type-> DATETIME

I want a query which can separate the Date and Time.

`select TIME(datetime_xyz) xyz_time_only, DATE(datetime_xyz) xyz_date_only from xyz where.....`

This returns me a separate date and time.

Now What i need is

- `select datetime_abc from abc where datetime_abc = xyz_date_only`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not missing something you could try:

```
SELECT datetime_abc FROM abc
WHERE DATE(datetime_abc) = xyz_date_only
```

Or you could try

```
SELECT datetime_abc 
FROM abc INNER JOIN xyz
    ON DATE(abc.datetime_abc) = DATE(xyz.datetime_xyz)
```

Comment: I tried that, It doesnt give any errors, but it wont return any rows. [But they do exist]

Comment: @umeshmoghariya: can you edit your question posting some row for every table?

Comment: ok.. your edit worked.. I am accepting your answer but i am curious if i want to do "select datetime_abc from abc where datetime_abc = '2008-1-3'"

Comment: @umeshmoghariya: you should use default format for date (YYYY-MM-DD)  `select datetime_abc from abc where datetime_abc = '2008-01-03'`